# asp.net mvc website issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have converted my asp.net mvc project to asp.net mvc website.

Everything works fine under IIS but under Cassini it doesn't resolve the URLs, even though it does it when it's an MVC project.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: Why would you be running under Cassini? In the end it will probably run on IIS. But in the meantime you'll be wasting time on things thatwill not be present in production anyway. Is there any limitation that you can't run on IIS?

Comment: I suspect its because he wants to be able to press F5 to test it.

What I am not sure about is what do mean by "Event though it does it when its a MVC project"

Comment: Firstly, I wanted to run it on Cassini just to see if it works there. Second, I can still press F5 and debug even running under IIS. 
Third, "Even though is does it when its an MVC project" means that when I build the website as a webproject in VS (Visual Studio) it runs fine under Cassini but it does'nt if I use a website option in VS.

Answer (score 0):

As a comparison, one of the ways to get it to get MVC to work correctly in IIS6 is to have all requests for all files run though aspnet_isapi.dll filter. I believe this is called wildcard mapping. Is there a similar feature in Cassini?

See this doc for reference on setting up wildcard mapping in II6, perhaps it might jog an idea for setting up in Cassini.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

**Update**

There is a couple of references to cassini in the above link that may help.

Comment: AFAIK: Cassini is already a managed web server (more similar to IIS7 than IIS6) that serves ALL requests via .net - managed requests, because there's no other mechanism in it. But it has its quirks that prevent it from working as IIS7.

Comment: Rob - thanks for the info. It's been a long time since I played with Cassini.

Comment: Sorry guys, but nothing ya'll said had anything to do with my question !

Answer (score 0):

I have the following environment at work.

IIS6 on the desktop.
IIS7 on production server.  => Yeah I know!

So I use Cassini to debug everything and it works fine.  I do however make all the global.asax changes required to make it run in IIS 6 and I test that periodically.

When it comes time to deploy I switch on the IIS 6 site and give it a good test.  Nothing beats log files at this point.  I also use Dubug / Attach to process... / asp.net WP so that I can still debug if there are issues.

When we all go to IIS7 on the desktops that should stop all that and I can probably ditch Cassini.

Comment: Dude, what does all of this have to do with the question I posted ?